# Uniform convergence of product in ball $|z|<R$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Find a polynomial $P(z)$ such that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\right)e^{-P(z)}$$ converges uniformly in every ball $|z|<R$.

Maybe we should take log to get that the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\log\left(1+\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-P(z)\right)$$ converges.

By Taylor series, we can write $\log\left(1+z\right)=z+g(z)z^2$ for $|z|<1$, where $g(z)$ is analytic in $|z|<1$.

Let $B = \sup_{|z|<1/2}|g(z)|$.

Now, for $|z|<R$ and $n>4R^2$, so that $g\left(\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\right)<B$,  we can write $$\left|\log\left(1+\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-P(z)\right|=\left|\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}+g\left(\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2-P(z)\right|$$

So we should at least select $P(z)$ to contain the term $\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{n}}$. What to do next?

Comment: You need a higher-order Taylor approximation. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n})^k}$$ diverges for $k \leqslant 2$ and converges for $k > 2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, so I just expand one more term, so that $k=3$, and choose $P(z)$ to be just the first two terms of the expansion?

Comment: Yep. That works. You could, if you wish, add more terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something? An infinite product of nonzero complex numbers $\Pi_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ has no chance of converging if you do not have $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n = 1$.

Here the limit is $e^{-P(z)}$, so your only try is $P(z) =0$. But it fails.

Comment: The question is to find a polynomial $P(z)$. Sure, you may choose $P(z)$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow} P(z)=0$. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Oh so $P(z)$ can depend on $n$? Your question does not make that clear at all! If that's the case, you should at least write $P_n(z)$.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. :)